# How to use DRAQ5 and MitoTracker CMXros dyes to stain turtle erythrocytes?

Tags: cell-biology, staining

I am working on turtle species and want to use DRAQ5 and MitoTracker CMXRos to stain turtle nucleated erythrocytes. Can anyone suggest me a protocol to carry this stain out? Would the two stains complement each other?

Comment: Welcome to Biology. Why use two stains and not one? Could you provide additional info and a link to these staining methods?

Comment: Have you tried just using the manufacturer's recommended protocols? The structures bound by DRAQ5 and MitoTracker are pretty conserved across eukaryotes, so these reagents should work in just about any cell type.

Comment: I havent tried this yet, I got to know that DRAQ5, a far red fluorescent  stain is most used for flow cytometry analysis. Can any tell me whether it can be used for fluorescent microscopy observation along with Mitotracker red?

Comment: If yes suggest me the protocol to start.